# Broken partitions

Tags: partitioning, testdisk

I just managed to break my partitions (or partition tables) on my dual boot PC. It has a 500MiB EFI Partition, 215GiB Windows 10 and 64GiB Linux. I'm currently trying to fix it using testdisk on linux that is running on an USB drive. Unfortunetly it doesn't recognize my hardrive but only the USB partitions. However I can see my harddrive + partitions in GParted running on the USB.

This is the output from `fdisk -l`:

---

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 61.6 MiB, 64573440 bytes, 126120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 318.1 MiB, 333533184 bytes, 651432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 962 MiB, 1008779264 bytes, 1970272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 426.5 MiB, 447172608 bytes, 873384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1e9f1e5c

Device         Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *    368443584 500118151 131674568 62.8G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sda: 14.7 GiB, 15804137472 bytes, 30867456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x364209eb

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         64 3731283 3731220  1.8G cd unknown
/dev/sda2       3731284 3739475    8192    4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

---

Does anybody know how I can acces the harddrive using testdisk?

Comment: If an UEFI system why is it showing dos/MBR, it should be gpt. What does this show `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` and sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1`? One advantage of gpt is that there is a backup partition table at end of drive.

Comment: The partitions were broken after I resized the windows partition, so maybe it changed GPT to MBR? I thought MBR is the partition with the EFI bootloader in it.

output from gdisk scanning for MBR: [link] https://pastebin.com/z8TRkxF4
output from gdisk scanning for GPT: [link] https://pastebin.com/HtsrgR8t

sorry I cant paste longer than 400 characters

Comment: It seems that my linux partition (which I manually booted with grub) has MBR while windows and the EFI has GPT. But now everything except linux is "unallocated space". gdisk seems to properly recognize them. Can gdisk fix the partition table?

Comment: The gdisk output is not showing a difference between main & backup gpt partitions tables. Widnwos only boots with UEFI from gpt and only with BIOS from MBR(msdos). The MBR is both the first sector or Master Boot Record of a MBR partitioned drive. With gpt, there is a protective MBR, only so old disk tools see that and know drive has a "gpt" partition which is entire drive. But gpt then has all the real partitions. Resizing with Windows would not change drive configuration. Have you used testdisk with EFI/gpt setting, not MBR/dos/msdos?

Comment: The resize in windows was with some tool, because windows itself couldn't resize. The tool performed the resize after bootup. You mentioned that gdisk does not show a difference between main & bkup partition tables. I guess that the main one is completely gone now and there are only the backup tables left? How can I use testdisk with the EFI/GPT setting? Do I have to run it on a system with GPT and not with msdos like my linux is running now? Before the bad resize my linux was on a GPT file system. Thanks for your answers oldfred

Comment: If there really are my backup gpt partition tables I can simply restore my filesystem with the "b" and "c"-command from the gdisk recovery option right?

Comment: I thought your gdisk output did not show any difference between primary & backup. It says that directly when loading partition table and which version it is using.

Comment: It doesn‘t show a difference, you‘re right. So my partitions are fine, but I can‘t access them for some reason ? They show correctly in gdisk GPT scan. Is there any way to access them? And my EFI partition seems not to be formatted in FAT like it should if it shows up in gdisk under GPT?

Comment: The EFI system partition needs to be FAT32, did you change it? Back up any data, actually entire system and then change it back to FAT32, not reformat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to restore the lost partitions. It was so simple that I didn't see it:

I used `gdisk /dev/nvme0n1` and then the command `w`. gdisk already found the gpt partitions so I thought they were present on the SSD but the tables were only in the memory while using gdisk. After writing the tables back to the SSD everything was back to normal (except for Linux being on MBR). I can't use Linux anymore but I backed up all the files from it already, so it doesn't really matter.

Thanks for your help oldfred